# Tomcat is showing wrong http status

Tags: spring, http, jwt

I need some help.

I built an API on SPRING Tool Suite which verifies a JWT before to release any operation on API.
That is my JWT filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                     ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {

        Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request);
        if (authentication == null) {
            System.out.println("auth  null");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(BackEndUtilities.INVALID_TOKEN, BackEndUtilities.ERROR_MSG_INVALID_TOKEN);

        }
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication((Authentication) authentication);
    }catch(ExpiredJwtException ex) {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(BackEndUtilities.INVALID_TOKEN);


    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

When I get null value on my authentication I send HTTP status 401 to tell the login is required.

The constant BackEndUtilities.INVALID_TOKEN is the int value 401. I get this value when I'm running the API on STS server, but when I deploy the war file on TOMCAT 8.5 I keep getting the HTTP STATUS 403.

In both cases I've been getting the string  "auth  null" on console, that is just appears when the authentication is null. But WHY TOMCAT 8.5 is "changing" the status?

Someone knows why it's keep happening?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(BackEndUtilities.INVALID_TOKEN, BackEndUtilities.ERROR_MSG_INVALID_TOKEN);

this line stops the running processing on sts, but it does'n happens on TOMCAT.